# Want to add a custom author link to a single.php

Tags: author

I want to add a custom link to linkedin near author name. It should be very easy if it would be only one author, but now it's not. So, I have to add something on all single.php and somewhere the real links. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields). It will teach you how to add a linkedin box to a user's profile and how to display that in a post.